# Agile web development with rails ProductsControllerTest , meaning of :product symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and I have been reading the Agile web development with rails book. 
I am working on Iteration B1: Validating, and I am really confused by the symbol :product while I am working on the test. The question is about the ":product => @update"
I really have no idea what does this mean and where the :product symbol come from. I know it is a hash, but which table does it hash to?  what exactly does it do here? The code is as following. Thank you in advance.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @product = products(:one)
    @update = {
      :title       => 'Lorem Ipsum',
      :description => 'Wibbles are fun!',
      :image_url   => 'lorem.jpg',
      :price       => 19.95
    }
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:products)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create product" do
    assert_difference('Product.count') do
      ***post :create, :product => @update***
    end

    assert_redirected_to product_path(assigns(:product))
  end

  # ...

  test "should show product" do
    get :show, :id => @product.to_param
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, :id => @product.to_param
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update product" do
    put :update, :id => @product.to_param, :product => @update
    assert_redirected_to product_path(assigns(:product))
  end

  # ...

  test "should destroy product" do
    assert_difference('Product.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, :id => @product.to_param
    end

    assert_redirected_to products_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing magical about this construct. The `@update` is a variable name that references a hash. The hash is declared earlier in your test file.

```
@update = {
  :title       => 'Lorem Ipsum',
  :description => 'Wibbles are fun!',
  :image_url   => 'lorem.jpg',
  :price       => 19.95
}
```

This hash contains new data that should be passed to the `update` action in the `products` controller. It's confusing because of the way the variable is named. A better name might help:

```
@product_attributes
```

The `products#update` action expects a hash containing updated data. That data is used to update the object.

The following line in your test...

```
post :update, :product => @update
```

Corresponds to this line you *probably* have in your products controller:

```
if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
```

Notice `params[:product]`. It's basically saying "make a post request to `products#update` and pass it the `@update` hash as `:product`.

And that explains the symbol part. The `:product` symbol in your test is the name of the parameter that contains the product data, that the update action expects.

```
post :update, :product => @update
```

In theory you can call it whatever you want. But per convention it helps to call it the resource name.